# How to distinguish between two identical USB drives?

Tags: mount, usb

Running Ubuntu 16.  I have two external USB drives and both are encrypted with Bitlocker.  I am mounting them using dislocker.  The problem is both drives are the same model and size so I don't know how to differentiate between them.  I need to be able to do this BEFORE mounting them via dislocker so I can make sure they are mounted to the right place.

This is the command and output I run to get drive information:

```
user@ubuntu:~$ sudo lsblk -o NAME,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL,MODEL

sdd                      3.7T                                                  My Passport 25E2
└─sdd1                   3.7T
sdg                      3.7T                                                  My Passport 25E2
└─sdg1                   3.7T
```

I'm guessing there's no label since it's a bitlocker drive that's not mounted yet.  Is there any way to change the 'MODEL' so I can distinguish between the drives?  Or make sure they always have the same USB id?

Comment: `ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid/` might show different UUIDs; if not (because of bitlocker) `ls -l /dev/disk/by-partuuid/`may be another possible solution.

Comment: Or perhaps blkid

Answer (score 3):

You can change the LABEL of each drive.

For ext2/3/4 partitions:

```
e2label /dev/sdg newlabel
```

For fat16/32:

```
mlabel /dev/sdg:newlabel
```